# Uploading text file to WCF RESTful service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, web

I created a simple RESTful WCF service with a single method for receiving files and a simple client that uploads a file. The files are simple text files (of course I would like to upload binary files later).

The service will be published for many types of clients so I would like to use an implementation that does not add a service reference.

Am I doing this correctly?

Why do I get a *The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request* error when I try to upload a simple 1Mb text file?

**Edit:**
*The system works correctly if my file has only a size of 3.7kb. This means I just have to configure the service to accept larger packets. How do I do that?*

**Service:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Data Service REST service that handles data upload.
    /// </summary>
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
    RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class DataService : Common.Contracts.IDataService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Uploads a data file to the server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">The filename.</param>
        /// <param name="fileContent">Content of the file.</param>
        public string UploadFile(string filename, Stream fileContent)
        {
            return filename;
        }
    }
```

**Service config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <!--
        Configure the WCF REST service base address 
        via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"
             automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Contract:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Data Service service contract interface.
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDataService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Uploads a data file to the server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">The filename.</param>
        /// <param name="fileContent">Content of the file.</param>
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/upload?filename={filename}", 
        Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        string UploadFile(string filename, System.IO.Stream fileContent);
    }
```

**Client**

```
WebChannelFactory<IDataService> cf = 
new WebChannelFactory<IDataService>(
                  new Uri(Settings.Default.UrlService));
IDataService channel = cf.CreateChannel();
StreamReader fileContent = new StreamReader(path, false);

string response = channel.UploadFile(path, fileContent.BaseStream);
```

Comment: Can you post the server and client configuration in your config files.

Comment: This is all I have. The web.config files are the ones generated by default. Because my client should not be strongly dependent on the web service I did not add a service reference. Do you think I should have?

Comment: Where have you defined your endpoint?

Comment: I added the <system.serviceModel> section of my service. It was never touched, this is how it was generated. I hope this is what you referred to with your question. I really am a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace your standardEndpoint element with the below:

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="500000" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000" >          
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />          
        </standardEndpoint>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has something to do with the maxReceivedMessageSize that you've got set in your config bindings.

Do you get the 400 when you upload something really small?

Comment: Excellent question, I will test it now. I only tried to upload 1M+ files so far.

Comment: No, I do not receive the error when I upload 3.7kb. Please tell me how can I configure my service to accept larger packets?